# How can I display the details in one line in HTML?

Tags: html

I have a script written in Python which will pass a list to a HTML file. I have a problem in displaying  the elements in the html page. As per the code written below, the elements are displayed vertically down as a list. I wanted the elements to be displayed in a single line horizontally.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<div id="content">
    {% for item in VOD1 %}
       <li>ID: {{ item[0] }}</li><li> Title: {{ item[1] }}</b></li>
       <img src="{{ item[2] }}" alt="dummy.jpg"> </img>
    {% endfor %}
    {% for item in VOD2 %}
       <li>ID: {{ item[0] }}</li><li> Title: {{ item[1] }}</li>
       <img src="{{ item[2] }}" alt="dummy.jpg"> </img>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried by adding a '-' after the '%' in the for loop to trim the white spaces but don't work. If I remove the line break then assets are displayed in a line but it's in a auto fit manner.3 assets details are displayed in each line instead of the whole details in a single line. Can someone please shed some light into this?

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML code?

Comment: @ManojKumar .. Sorry, i didn't get you. What is a generated HTML code. I am not an expert in HTML.

Comment: Your current code is dynamic i.e. it will output a bunch of code in the browser. Copy paste the code that is shown in the browser.

Comment: There is no code in the browser. I could see the details i wanted but not in the order which i wanted. Sorry, if I am missing anything.

Comment: Check this out. 
    {% for item in VOD1 %} ID: {{ item[0] }} Title: {{ item[1] }}  dummy.jpg {% endfor %} {% for item in VOD2 %} ID: {{ item[0] }} Title: {{ item[1] }} dummy.jpg {% endfor %}

Comment: *the elements are displayed vertically down as a list* How is that displayed then? :) Any demo link of the output?

Comment: @ManojKumar.. Yeah, the elements are displayed in a Vertical list down. I wanted the details to be displayed in a Horizontal list. I am sorry, this is an internal tool and hence you't access.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91573/discussion-between-roshan-r-and-manoj-kumar).

Comment: Just copy and paste whatever you have in Notepad. Try http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @ManojKumar  Please find it in https://jsfiddle.net/roshKrish/bgtLp6d0/1/

Comment: @ManojKumar .. Any updates?

Comment: I can think of Dominik's second solution. It is the best way to do what you need.

Comment: @ManojKumar .. I am not able to get the details in a horizontal line as per the solution. Shall i share the HTML file and CSS file for you to check?

Comment: Yes please! Make the exact demo of what you have now again using http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @ManojKumar .. Please check https://jsfiddle.net/roshKrish/bgtLp6d0/1/

Comment: Post the link without request to localhost URL of the images, it is not loading for him.

Comment: Shall i share the HTML and CSS in imgur?

Answer (score 1):

If I get you correctly, you want the `<li>` elements to be displayed `inline` rather than as `block` elements:

```css
li { display: inline-block }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>ID: 1</li>
  <li>Title: foo</li>
  <li><img src="//lorempixel.com/400/200"</li>
</ul>
```

*Edit:* as I think of it, you could also want each ID/Title as a header to the image, and every of those components horizontally aside each other. Like so:

```css
div, li { display: inline-block }
img { display: block }
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>ID: 1</li>
    <li>Title: foo</li>
  </ul>
  <img src="//lorempixel.com/400/200">
</div>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>ID: 2</li>
    <li>Title: bar</li>
  </ul>
  <img src="//lorempixel.com/400/300">
</div>
```

Comment: I thought of posting this but images are not within `<li>`. This might work but leaving the images behind vertically. I think if OP can show the full code generated, it would be easy for us to find him a solution.

Comment: @Dominik.. As i mentioned, i tried all the options you mentioned above but didn't get the list in a single line.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or sketch or whatever of how you need it?

Comment: @Dominik.. I don't have that much reputation to attach a screen shot. Is there any other option?

Comment: @Roshan host it somewhere else and link to it. A [gist](https://gist.github.com) or on [imgur](http://imgur.com/) or even in a dropbox...

Comment: @DominikSchreiber .. I uploaded the image into http://imgur.com/0BfJyps. The list is displayed vertically, I wanted the details in horizontal line.

Comment: This is displayed in the browser right? Can you just open `Inspect element` and copy-paste the code?

Comment: I don't get it. By *details* you mean `ID` and `Title`? Try my second example with `li{display:inline-block} img{display:block}` as css.

Comment: @ManojKumar.. If i open inspect element.. i could see just HTML code for only 5 lines. But if i do a copy and paste on a notepad, i could see the details of the elements on the browser and that content is huge. Let me know which one you wanted?

Comment: @DominikSchreiber.. I updated my css file with the changes you mentioned, but still no help.